# How do I widen a hole in my porcelain kitchen sink?

Tags: plumbing, drill

My faucet recently broke, so I replaced it with a new faucet and sprayer. To put in the sprayer, we removed the dishwasher air gap - with predictable results. I've replaced the air gap in its hole. I'd still like to use the sprayer; however, I don't have any other holes of the right size.

I do have a 1/2" hole on the other side of the porcelain sink that was previously used for a filtered water faucet. How can I widen this hole to the 1-3/8" that I'll need for the sprayer?

Comment: Look under the sink where the hole is.  Do you see any indication of a knockout? Most sinks have predetermined hole locations, where the material is weakened so that it can be "easily" popped out.

Comment: Are you sure it is porcelain? That is not common for kitchen sinks; usually enameled cast iron, enameled pressed sheet steel, or stainless. There are vitreous kitchen sinks but they are usually those "vintage" farmhouse sinks that have an apron front and mount on the wall.

Comment: In the US, "porcelain" in the context of cooking pots or bathroom fittings often means a vitreous enamel coating over cast iron or steel.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend installing a faucet with an integral sprayer as a less complex alternative to modifying a porcelain fixture.

[image]